# Searching folder for a specific XML file using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a folder with multiple XML files and all of them have the same structure, with different attribute values.

```
File1.Xml
<Parent attribtueValue="A">
  <Child>
     <Data1>grape</Data1>
     <Data2>sour</Data2>
  </Child>
</Parent>

File2.Xml
<Parent attribtueValue="B">
  <Child>
     <Data1>apple</Data1>
     <Data2>sweet</Data2>
  </Child>
</Parent>
```

I have a different Xml (tree.xml) that looks like this:

```
 <Tree>   
   <Branch></Branch>
   <attributeValue>B</attributeValue>
 </Tree>
```

I am doing an XSLT transform to transform tree.xml to look like this:

```
<Tree>
  <Branch></Branch>
  <Data1>apple</Data1>
  <Data2>sweet</Data2>
</Tree>
```

Now, the transformation works fine if I take one particular document from the folder as

```
<xsl:variable name="file" select="'C:\docs\file2.xml'"/>
<xsl:variable name="info" select="document($file)/Parent/Child/."/>
```

I want to be able to take the folder as a parameter input, and loop through to find the right xml, through attributeValue, and use the Data within that to transform my tree.xml. I am new to XSLT and I can't find any help with this in the limited research that I've done so far.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Well with an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon or XmlPrime you can usually use the `collection` function to access a directory or folder of XML files e.g. with Saxon `collection('file:///C:/docs?select=*.xml')` would allow you to load all `.xml` files in that folder. See http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!sourcedocs/collections

Comment: As stated above, XSLT 2.0 should be your choice. But in 1.0 you could create another simple xml with the list of file names. pass that instead into your transform and then iterate over that using the document() function on each name in the list.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I'm trying not to use any external libraries, and do it with XSLT 1.0 if at all possible.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, but I wouldn't have all the filenames beforehand to create a filelist xml. It's a dynamic situation.

Comment: well, your two requiements are not compatible. pick one. you could use XSL 2 or have a simple program that makes the list.